# Android application GUI Design

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a problem in android application interface design(GUI).

For example when we insert an editText field the height is too big. Yes we can change the width and bit modify.

But does anyone have any link of a reference or idea of how to design the exact design we want. And when we add 2 -3 editText(views) the entire space finish. have to scroll to go through entire page.

And to design the GUI for all kind of screen sizes, what are the standard things that have to follow. I searched but didn't find exact answer.

Any link to a good reference or idea is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Add more details to your question, and if you have a sample of how your UI looks like, that would nice.

Answer (score 0):

set the layout of text edit with:

```
layout_width="wrap_content" //wrap_content fill the dimension like the content and fill_content all the space free
layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your app resolution free you have to take care for the following items

1. Widgets in your activity (wrap_content, match_parent, fill_parent, or left, right gravity in relative layout etc)
2. Icons and Images in your activity (You have to keep icons of 3 different sizes in 3 different drawable folders, hdpi, mdpi and ldpi and if you are making your app for tablets also then xdpi (i think))
3. You have to provide similar text sizes for different screen sizes (3 sizes should be suffice I believe) You can make a general xml file for this and keep it in another drawable folder.

Let me know if you need more detail on this.